# How do you check to see if the 1st letter in a string is equal to something?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, substring

In my if statement, I'm trying to check if the first letter of a `string` is either `Y` or `y`, and then proceed as such. Below is what I have, but I don't believe it to be correct.

```
System.out.print("Do you wish to do another calculation (Yes/No): ")
      option = scan.next();
         if (option.substring(0,1) == "N" && option.substring(0,1) == "n" )
         {
            System.out.println("Have a good day");
            System.exit(0);
         }
bmi.setOption(option);
```

I instantiated `option` as `String option = " ";` earlier on in my program. I know how to check if strings equal a certain character, however am having trouble checking to see if only the FIRST character of the string is equal to something.

Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is that you're comparing strings with `==`; use `.equals()` instead (in addition to the `&&` vs `||` problem mentioned by @Victory).

Comment: You can also convert to lowercase `substring(0,1).toLowerCase()` and perform only one check

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(option.charAt(0)) == 'n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first char can't be both "N" and "n", looks like you want it to be "N" or "n"

```
     if (option.substring(0,1).equals("N") || option.substring(0,1).equals("n") )
```

We had == before which is more like a memory comparison we want to compare value so we use `equals`

Comment: Also,  String.startsWith(prefix)

Comment: Thank you! I used the startsWith() method in the string class and the program works great. I didn't realize that was there and missed it in the Java docs.

Comment: This solution allocates 4 additional strings, 2 for substrings and 2 for "n" and "N". Also startsWith() solution allocates additional 2 strings. All those allocations can be omitted.

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski yes i think you solution is better, i went with the solution that is probably more inline with Arkoh's skill level. I have up voted your answer.

Comment: @Victory so, IMO, since question author seems to be a beginner it seems to be a good idea to tell him about good practices :)