# Java/Android: how to find the first characters of a string if it equals other string

Tags: java, string, search, split, chars

I have a **String Array #1 countries[]** and I have another **String Array #2 splitr_str[]** that have the same values 
but it split in half.

What I want is to to check which value of the #2 Array **match the first half value** of the #1 String Array which has the full word.

Here's an example:

```
String[] countries = new String[]{"USA", "Spain" ,"Germany"};

String[] split_str = new String[]{"Sp", "ain", "A" ,"US" ,"Ger", "ma","ny"};
```

Now i want to detect only the first half of the countries values that match the ssplit_str value

**for USA i just want to pick "US" which is in**

```
 split_str[3]
```

**and if i found it ? i pick "A" which is**

```
 split_str[2]
```

And so on.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271035/how-do-you-check-to-see-if-the-1st-letter-in-a-string-is-equal-to-something it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using for loops. As I just learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java), you an use a label and `break` to easily break out of both loops once the match has been found.

```
outerloop:
for( String country : countries){
     for( String segment : split_str) {
        if( country.startsWith( segment ) ) {
            // do something here when the segment has been detected
            break outerloop;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: you made it look soooo EASY! wow i didn't know about "startsWith" method Thank you Keara Have a Nice Day!

Comment: Happy I could help! You have a nice day too.

Comment: i just don't know why i can't break the loop if i detected the segment even that i put break; inside IF . i'm confused

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about that. I'll edit my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit inefficient. But its the best solution I could find

```
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < split_str.length; j++)
        {
            if(countries[i].substring(0, (countries[i].length() / 2) + 1).contains(split_str[j]))
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < split_str.length; k++)
                {
                    if (countries[i].substring((countries[i].length() / 2) + 1, countries[i].length()).contains(split_str[k]))
                    {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you Aayush Gupta! this also works perfecly too! have a nice day !