# How to check if a period or a bracket exist first in a String?

Tags: java, string, symbols

Is it possible to check in a string a period or a square bracket comes first?
I have tried this simple code , is working fine, but looking for a good approach. please help. thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "timedLeg[0].service.carriers[0].ref";
    checkString(str);
}

private static void checkString(String str) {
    if(str.contains("[") || str.contains("."))
    {
        int indBr = 0,indPrd = 0;
        if(str.contains("["))
            indBr = str.indexOf("[");
        if(str.contains("."))
            indPrd = str.indexOf(".");

        if(indPrd!=0 && indBr!=0){
            if(indPrd<indBr)
                    System.out.println("period comes first");
                else
                    System.out.println("bracket comes first");

        }
```

Comment: What's the significance of `indPrd!=0 && indBr!=0`? What if it's the first character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check to see if the 1st letter in a string is equal to something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271035/how-do-you-check-to-see-if-the-1st-letter-in-a-string-is-equal-to-something)

Comment: @Mark OP isn't trying to check if the first character is a `.` or `[`, they want to know which of those characters occurs first in the string.

Comment: You're searching for each character 3 times. Just call `indexOf()` once; if it's absent it'll return -1.

Comment: Just obtain the first match of the regular expression `[.\[]`. If the match is `'.'`, `'.'` comes first, if the match is `'['`, `'['` comes first, if there is no match the string contains neither of those characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for each character more times than you need to; just check once using [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and use the fact that it returns `-1` if the character is not found to control your logic. Updating your code:

```java
private static void checkString(String str) {
    int indBr = str.indexOf("[");
    int indPrd = str.indexOf(".");
 
    if(indPrd >= 0 && indBr >= 0) {
        if(indPrd < indBr)
            System.out.println("period comes first");
        else
            System.out.println("bracket comes first");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No bracket or period");
    }
}
```

Java demo on [ideone](https://ideone.com/IYU0yV)

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Is it possible to check in a string a period or a square bracket comes first? ..."*

Use the *[String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))* method.

```java
int a = Math.min(str.indexOf('['), str.indexOf('.'));
if (a != -1) System.out.println(str.charAt(a) + " is first");
```

Or, without *[Math#min](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,int))*.

```java
int a, b;
if ((a = str.indexOf('[')) != -1)
    if ((b = str.indexOf('.')) != -1)
        System.out.println((a < b ? '[' : '.') + " is first");
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Regex approach:

(since you tagged the question with regex)

I am not familiar with Java, but you probably are able to access captured groups. This Regex captures a string either into `bracketFirst` of `dotFirst` depending on which comes first:

```
^(?:(?<bracketFirst>[^.]*\[.*)|(?<dotFirst>[^\[]*\..*))$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/t13QKI/latest

`^` Asserts start of string

`(?: ...)` Non-capturing group carrying the two options

- `(?<bracketFirst>[^.]*\[.*)` Matches if a bracket comes first by asserting no `.` comes before `[`
- `|` OR
- `(?<dotFirst>[^\[]*\..*)` Matches if `.` before  `[`

`$` Asserts end of line

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all other chars then use `startsWith()`:

```
private static void checkString(String str) {
    if (str.replaceAll("[^\\[.]", "").startsWith(".")) {
        System.out.println("period comes first");
    } else {
        System.out.println("bracket comes first");
    }
}
```

The regex `[^\\[.]` means "any character not a `[` or a `.`", so replacing those with a blank `""` "deletes" them. This is very slightly "expensive", but unless your string is huge, we're talking microseconds.

Comment: If there isn't a `.` in the string, this will say a bracket comes first regardless of whether there is a `[` in the string or not.

Comment: @nick as will OP's code

Comment: True. And I guess they say "it's working fine" so perhaps they never have strings that don't have either `.` or `[` in them.